# How to make linux detect/re-probe monitors with intel i915 driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, monitors

I have a laptop running linux with nvidia optimus/intel hybrid graphics where all outputs are connected to the intel card. It is driven by the i915 driver.

An external monitor or beamer is discovered only one time a boot cycle: If I disable or unplug it (and then plug it again), it cannot be enabled again, because the linux kernel does not detect it anymore: There are no udev or acpi events on plug/unplug and the sysfs, in my case `/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/status`, indicates that the output is disconnected. After a reboot the display is detected again, and again exactly one time. Suspending/hibernating and resuming suffice as well, but only if the output is uplugged while rebooting.

I think this is somehow related to the kernel probing/reprobing for output devices on boot. Can the kernel be somehow induced to re-probe for monitors, and thus to hopefully detect them again?

Comment: Is this under X? Just running `xrandr` (without `--current`) might be enough... Otherwise, I have an incantation to force-enable an output, but it's on a laptop at home.

Comment: This is in TTY as well, only worse: re*enabling* of TTY output on an external display seems randomly. But X should not have anything to do with the *detection* of the output as the kernel does not even detect it. @derobert: I would be grateful for the incantation!

Comment: I'll grab it when I get home (sometime later tonight) ... but it's for X, not console. There are some i915 options that might help too (try `/sbin/modinfo i915`), but really this is supposed to work automatically :-(

Comment: I added the xrandr stuff, no idea if it is of any use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't the xrandr-approach the I know works in X, but for console you can try this — you can *write* to that `/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/status` file as well. I couldn't find proper documentation, but thankfully Linux is open source. Reviewing the [source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_sysfs.c#L116), it looks like it takes a few values: `detect`, `on`, `on-digital`, and `off`.

So `echo detect > /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/status` should force a re-check for a monitor. Or `echo on-digital > /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/status` might manage to turn it on, regardless of what the detection thinks.

**edit:** Under X, I've used this to deal with HDMI that did not detect being plugged it — it'll force-enable the output. But unfortunately video only, HDMI audio won't work (and apparently isn't possible without a kernel patch):

```
xrandr --newmode "Mode 2" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "Mode 2"
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "Mode 2" --right-of LVDS-1
```

All those numbers specify the video timings; normally it's auto-detected, the easiest way to get them is to grab the mode it's using when you've booted with it so it's working (`xrandr --verbose` will show them).

Comment: Force-enabling the monitor via sysfs/`on` worked, however, auto-detection (`detect`) did not. Thank you for the xrandr stuff, even if the modes were no problem as they were detected correctly after force-enabling. And thank you very much for the kernel-related part of the answer!